# Essence of Laziness. Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am learning a haskell for a few days and the laziness is something like buzzword. Because of the fact I am not familiar with laziness ( I have been working mainly with non-functional languages ) it is not easy concept for me.

So, I am asking for any excerise / example which show me what laziness is in the fact.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Take a list of numbers from 0 to *infinity*, map a function over it (iterate over it and, say, multiply all values by 2), then print out the first 10 numbers. – With laziness you can approach this task exactly as described; without it you'd have to think and code it very differently.

Comment: Quote something from your tutorial that you are having a problem with: a definition, a statement, a code snippet — whatever mentions laziness. Explain what your specific dofficulty is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something interesting: dynamic programming, the bane of every intro. algorithms student, becomes *simple* and *natural* when written in a lazy and functional language. Take [the example of string edit distance](http://jelv.is/blog/Lazy-Dynamic-Programming/). This is the problem of measuring how similar two DNA strands are or how many bytes changed between two releases of a binary executable or just how 'different' two strings are. The dynamic programming algorithm, expressed mathematically, is simple:

```
let:

• d_{i,j} be the edit distance of
  the first string at index i, which has length m
  and the second string at index j, which has length m
• let a_i be the i^th character of the first string
• let b_j be the j^th character of the second string

define:

d_{i,0} = i                   (0 <= i <= m)
d_{0,j} = j                   (0 <= j <= n)
d_{i,j} = d_{i - 1, j - 1}    if a_i == b_j
d_{i,j} = min {               if a_i != b_j
  d_{i - 1, j} + 1 (delete)
  d_{i, j - 1} + 1 (insert)
  d_{i - 1, j - 1} + 1 (modify)
}

return d_{m, n}
```

And the algorithm, expressed in Haskell, follows the same shape of the algorithm:

```
distance a b = d m n
  where (m, n) = (length a, length b)
        a'     = Array.listArray (1, m) a
        b'     = Array.listArray (1, n) b

        d i 0 = i
        d 0 j = j
        d i j
          | a' ! i ==  b' ! j = ds ! (i - 1, j - 1)
          | otherwise = minimum [ ds ! (i - 1, j)     + 1
                                , ds ! (i, j - 1)     + 1
                                , ds ! (i - 1, j - 1) + 1
                                ]

        ds = Array.listArray bounds
               [d i j | (i, j) <- Array.range bounds]
        bounds = ((0, 0), (m, n))
```

In a strict language we wouldn't be able to define it so straightforwardly because the cells of the array would be strictly evaluated. In Haskell we're able to have the definition of each cell reference the definitions of other cells because Haskell is lazy – the definitions are only evaluated at the very end when `d m n` asks the array for the value of the last cell. A lazy language lets us set up a graph of standing dominoes; it's only when we ask for a value that we need to compute the value, which topples the first domino, which topples all the other dominoes. (In a strict language, we would have to set up an array of closures, doing the work that the Haskell compiler does for us automatically. It's easy to transform implementations between strict and lazy languages; it's all a matter of which language expresses which idea better.)

The [blog post](http://jelv.is/blog/Lazy-Dynamic-Programming/) does a much better job of explaining all this.

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell you can create an infinite list. For instance, all natural numbers:

```
[1,2..]
```

If Haskell loaded all the items in memory at once that wouldn't be possible. To do so you would need infinite memory.

Laziness allows you to get the numbers as you need them.

Answer (score 2):

> So, I am asking for any excerise / example which show me what laziness is in the fact.

Click on Lazy on [haskell.org](http://haskell.org) to get the canonical example. There are many other examples just like it to illustrate the concept of delayed evaluation that benefits from not executing some parts of the program logic. Lazy is certainly not slow, but the opposite of eager evaluation common to most imperative programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

Laziness is a consequence of non-strict function evaluation. Consider the "infinite" list of 1s:

```
ones = 1:ones
```

At the time of definition, the `(:)` function isn't evaluated; `ones` is just a promise to do so when it is necessary. Such a time would be when you pattern match:

```
myHead :: [a] -> a
myHead (x:rest) = x
```

When `myHead ones` is called, `x` and `rest` are needed, but the pattern match against `1:ones` simply binds `x` to 1 and `rest` to `ones`; we don't need evaluate `ones` any further at this time, so we don't.

The syntax for infinite lists, using the `..` "operator" for arithmetic sequences, is sugar for calls to `enumFrom` and `enumFromThen`. That is

```
-- An infintite list of ones
ones = [1,1..] -- enumFromThen 1 1

-- The natural numbers
nats = [1..] -- enumFrom 1
```

so again, laziness just comes from the non-strict evaluation of `enumFrom`.

Comment: "Laziness is a consequence of non-strict function evaluation" is not quite true. In your example, `ones` is not a function, it's an (infinite) list. And in an eager language (OCaml for instance) it would indeed lead to an infinite loop. But we could exploit the fact that evaluation is not performed under lambdas to model the same lazy list using e.g. `type 'a stream = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a)` and defininig `let rec ones () = Cons (1, ones)`.

Comment: It's really a finite list with 1 and an unevaluated call to `ones` since `(:)` isn't strict. The "infinite" nature of the list only becomes apparent when you need to fully evaluate the tail with something like `tail ones` or `show ones`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike with other languages, Haskell decouples the creation and definition of an object....  You can easily watch this in action using `Debug.Trace`.

You can define a variable like this

```
aValue = 100
```

(the value on the right hand side could include a complicated evaluation, but let's keep it simple)

To see if this code ever gets called, you can wrap the expression in `Debug.Trace.trace` like this

```
import Debug.Trace

aValue = trace "evaluating aValue" 100
```

Note that this doesn't change the definition of `aValue`, it just forces the program to output "evaluating aValue" whenever this expression is actually created at runtime.

(Also note that `trace` is considered unsafe for production code, and should only be used to debug).

Now, try two experiments....  Write two different `main`s

```
main = putStrLn $ "The value of aValue is " ++ show aValue
```

and

```
main = putStrLn "'sup"
```

When run, you will see that the first program actually creates aValue (you will see the "creating aValue" message, while the second does not.

This is the idea of laziness....  You can put as many definitions in a program as you want, but only those that are used will be actually created at runtime.

The real use of this can be seen with objects of infinite size.  Many lists, trees, etc. have an infinite number of elements.  Your program will use only some finite number of values, but you don't want to muddy the definition of the object with this messy fact.  Take for instance the infinite lists given in other answers here....

```
[1..] -- = [1,2,3,4,....]
```

You can again see laziness in action here using trace, although you will have to write out a variant of [1..] in an expanded form to do this.

```
f::Int->[Int]
f x = trace ("creating " ++ show x) (x:f (x+1)) --remember, the trace part doesn't change the expression, it is just used for debugging
```

Now you will see that only the elements you use are created.

```
main = putStrLn $ "the list is " ++ show (take 4 $ f 1)
```

yields
    creating 1
    creating 2
    creating 3
    creating 4
    the list is [1,2,3,4]

and

```
main = putStrLn "yo"
```

will not show any item being created.